# How to detect file copy over local network with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, io

I've to create a simple application with .NET Framework that detects when a remote user copy some file from the machine that the application will run on.

Eg.

- **Machine1** (The application will run here)
- **Machine2**

A user on the **Machine2** access a shared directory on the **Machine1** and copies some files to some **Machine2** directory.

I need log the file name that was copied and the IP/DNS that request the copy.

Is there some Windows Message to do it?

Or even any IO class?

> A requirement is that I have to do this through a custom application.

Comment: Have a look at [FileSystemWatcher](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F).

Comment: Hello @Reticulated Spline!
I know something about this class but I saw that it does not detect when someone copied the file eg: Ctrl + C from a remote machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not detect from a C# program if a file has been accessed, there is no message or exposed API that will tell you when it happens. You need to go a lower level in the OS. The normal way of doing this is you set windows itself to do the monitoring via group policy under the `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Advanced Audit Policy Configuration\Audit Policies\` then enable `Object Access: File Share`.

This will create a audit log entry like the following

```
Log Name:      Security 
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 
Date:          8/14/2013 2:08:25 AM 
Event ID:      5145 
Task Category: Detailed File Share 
Level:         Information 
Keywords:      Audit Success 
User:          N/A 
Computer:      RootMS01.Reskit.com 
Description: 
A network share object was checked to see whether client can be granted desired access. 
Subject: 
        Security ID:           RESKIT\Administrator 
        Account Name:          Administrator 
        Account Domain:               RESKIT 
        Logon ID:              0x49199 
Network Information:    
        Object Type:           File 
        Source Address:               10.10.10.11 
        Source Port:           61361 
Share Information: 
        Share Name:            \\*\Shares 
        Share Path:            \??\C:\Shares 
        Relative Target Name:  UserHomeFolder\LSkywalker\Projects.txt 
Access Request Information: 
        Access Mask:           0x120089 
        Accesses:              READ_CONTROL 
                              SYNCHRONIZE 
                              ReadData (or ListDirectory) 
                              ReadEA 
                              ReadAttributes 
Access Check Results: 
        READ_CONTROL:  Granted by Ownership 
                              SYNCHRONIZE:   Granted by        D:(A;;FA;;;WD) 
                              ReadData (or ListDirectory):  Granted by        D:(A;;FA;;;WD) 
                              ReadEA: Granted by     D:(A;;FA;;;WD)
```

You can see the file that was accessed and the IP of the machine accessing it is in the log, all you need to do is write a C# program that [reads the log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry(v=vs.110).aspx) and pulls out the information you need.

[Here is a detailed technet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/08/27/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers.aspx) explaining how to set it up.

Comment: Hi Scott, Tks for reply.

Can i perform this task on a computer with Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, audit policies are not specific to server versions of windows.

Comment: It not work on Windows 8/8.1 :(. Just on Pro/Enterprise versions.

Comment: Well, yes, it is a pro/enterprize feature. Basic edition will not be able to do it.

Comment: Scott, is there another way to do this? (For all versions)

Comment: Not to my knowledge, getting extra features you can't do in the basic version is the point of having a pro version. If you want to use a pro feature you need to pay for the pro license.